# Anomalies when I unwrap the UV mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

After successfully producing an Unwrapped UV map on my file, I saw anomalies so I looked at the Stack Exchange listing that came up when I typed my question, and found how to remove most of them by using  W> Remove Doubles.  That still left two dots (vertices?) that I don't know how to get rid of.  Can you help?
[image]

Here is the same map after removing the doubles:
[image]

Also, a related question is how to get a UV image that I next created, big enough to cover the UV Map.  (Does that make sense?)

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time to get the best answers. You are welcome to ask as many separate questions as you need.

Comment: Those "2 vertices" may be 2 pieces of mesh containing a bunch of vertices which take so little place on UV map because they aren't unwrapped properly. Assign a test texture on the mesh, select these "vertices" in the UV map, grab them and look what will happen with texture on the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Also, as to texture size - you will need to select all and scale down to fit inside that main square that represents the image area. Add an image and choose UV Grid or Color Grid instead of Blank, and you will see the way the mesh UVs overhanging the edge 'repeat' across the image, especially if you paint on the texture.

Comment: It has been a while since I opened Blender.  These are very good comments.  I greatly value the Stack Exchange.  Thanks!